# cannot display a string in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class TheNumberGameDivTwo{
private:
public:
        string find( int n ){
    string n1 = "John";
    string n2 = "Brus";
    //cout << "Mahesh"<< n2 << n1;
    int i,q;
    q = 0;
    int k = n;
    i = n-1;
    for ( i = 2 ; i < k ; ++i ){
        if ( !(k % i) ){
            q += k / i;
            k = k % i;
        }
    }
    if ( q % 2 )
        return "John";
    else
        return "Brus";
}
};

int main(){
TheNumberGameDivTwo T;
cout << endl << T.find(6);
cout << endl << "End of Program " << endl;

system("PAUSE");
}
```

Error   1

```
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  
d:\my documents\visual studio 2012\c++\topcoder\topcoder\source1.cpp    34  1   TopCoder
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `#include <string>`